# SSD disappears from Boot configuration after installing Windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8, boot, installation, ssd

I just installed Windows 8.1 using an official install disk onto my Samsung EVO 850, but once I did this, the drive disappeared from my Boot menu...

The installer went all the way until the update installation as it asked me to reboot during that.

My machine is an Acer Predator...

Images can be found here:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/HtJWj.jpg

Whenever I try to boot it now, I get:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/SLbJz.jpg

Sidenote: I tried to plug in the correctly operating SSD of my laptop, but it doesn't show up as boot device either... I have tried to put it in every possible SATA slot

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the master boot record may be damaged during install. If it is a 2.5" disk, you can buy a external cable for about 15.00. I would use this cable on another computer. Plug it in and see if you can find the disk with disk management. If you can find it, reformat and reinstall. If not, the disk is likely damaged and needs to be replaced.